# Tomcat 8.5 Log To Syslog

Tags: tomcat, syslog, rsyslog, log4j

I have found a tutorial for logging from tomcat to syslog using log4j:
https://www.badllama.com/content/tomcat-7-logging-syslog-log4j

Sadly this doesn't work anymore in tomcat 8.5. As stated in the comments [of the documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/logging.html). Support for log4j has been removed.

Is there another way to log to syslog?